# How to make UIloader work?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, unhandled

I have this project at school, where I am supposed to make an image recognizer **not** importing any photos into Flash. Here's the error I´m getting:

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file

Anyway, this is the file (p.s. it's Norwegian. And yeah, I'm a noob, I know.)

http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/507257/recognizer-fla.html

I have tried similar methods, but nothing seems to work - again, I'm a noob. I have only been coding for two months.

Answer (score 0):

> not importing any photos into Flash

It's easy to load external image. You will need `Loader` class, image will be represented as instance of the `Bitmap` class. If you get IOError, I assume your url isn't correct.

Example:

```
var loader: Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/promo_650/public/stylus/1235529-taylor-swift-woman-of-the-year-617-409.jpg"));

function onComplete(e:Event):void{
    var bitmap: Bitmap = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content as Bitmap;
    addChild(bitmap);
    //Do whatever you want with the image
}
```